# What is a "hollow clause"?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Source: the Cambridge Grammar of the English language.

I saw this term "hollow clause" in a grammar book, but the grammar book doesn't explain thoroughly about it. It does say:

> Most non-finite clauses have no overt subject, but the interpretation of the clause requires that an understood subject be retrieved from the linguistic or non-linguistic context. There are also non-finite clauses in which a non-subject NP is missing:
>
> - John is easy [to please____] (where the missing object of please is understood as *John*)
> - This idea is worth [giving some thought to____] (where the complement of the preposition to is understood as *this idea*).
>
> Clauses of this kind we call hollow clauses.

Is it acceptable to write these sentences in this way?

John is easy to please himself.
These ideas worth giving to which some thought.

Comment: Can you tell us what the book **does** say about it?

Comment: Now we have the excerpt; which part(s) are you having trouble grasping?

Comment: Is it acceptable to write these sentences in this way. John is easy to please himself. These ideas worth giving to which some though.? @J.R.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo No, the omission of the object NPs in these idiomatic constructions is obligatory.

Comment: Hi Bavyan, I've added the information from your comment to your post. It's better to keep editing your question to improve it than to put extra information in the comments. Comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: If you wanted to reword the sentences, use the existing subject as the object and replace the subject with "It": It is easy to please John. It is worth giving some thought to these ideas.

Comment: The more I think about this, the weirder it gets. *Giving some thought to these ideas is worth it*. Is it worth it?  It's worth it.