# "Pretty to see, hard to catch". Vs. "pretty to be seen, hard to be caught

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

> - A girl should be like a butterfly. Pretty to see, hard to catch.

I want to know how this could be?

-Pretty to see (someone) or to be see (by someone), or hard to be caught instead of hard to catch.

I think "pretty to be seen" and "hard to be caught" are more grammatical.

Because if we said that is pretty to see, that would mean if she is not beautiful, or ugly, she would not be able to see.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement. 'Pretty' contruction is a lil bit different; it's explained there.

Comment: Thank you. But i want to know how could you have solution to each problem such as this one? Do you have any good references to read about this case? @user178049

Comment: I'm writing an answer. Huddleston and Pullum (2002)called this a hollow clause. There's also a brief explanation in *A Student Introduction to English Grammar*, written by the same authors.

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/140604/

Comment: You have to understand: Some proverbs are written to be more catchy than grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

- Pretty to see
- Hard to catch

In modern grammar, these are called hollow non-finite clauses. These non-finite clauses have a non-subject gap (i.e. a missing constituent) that's recoverable from the context. The gap usually corresponds the subject in the main clause. Herein, gaps are marked with <s>strikethrough</s>.

> Pretty to see <s>a butterfly</s>
>
> Hard to catch <s>a butterfly</s>

These hollow clauses are licensed by the adjectives, which are—in this particular context—*pretty* and *hard*.

The latter is commonly analyzed as a *tough construction*¹ because it's 'licensed' by tough adjectives (e.g. *hard, easy, difficult*).

---

¹ <sub>Biber et al. in *Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English* analyze it as an object-to-subject raising.</sub>

Comment: Why catch is different from pretty?

Comment: Look at this example: he was eager to leave. What about this?

Comment: @StevanSlewa 'eager' is not a tough adjective; it's a [control](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/277727/178049) adjective. I don't understand the first sentence. Why are you comparing the verb and the adjective?

Comment: @Stevan Slewa: You may be getting misled by the difference between ***see / look at*** as much as any difference between ***catch*** and ***pretty***. Consider ***Pretty to look at, expensive to break***, which would be perfectly "natural" as a sign in a china shop, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That construction, **pretty to see** is like  "tasty to eat" or "nice to hear" or "good to know".

> The stew is tasty to eat.
>
> That music is pleasant to hear.

The stew isn't eating and the music isn't hearing. Rather the stew is eaten and the music is heard.

You can identify such constructions by the absence of the perceiver, who is present only indirectly by way of the adjective: things are *tasty* to *someone*.   Music is *pleasant* to *someone*.

In a sense, the adjective in tandem with the non-finite verb acts as a proxy for an abstract perceiver.

That makes such constructions a cousin to the passive.

> It is to die for.

Comment: This answer is helpful to understand.

Comment: A good explanation, But what about your last example "it is to die for" I don't understand it. Do you mean such "it is difficult to someone to die for money"? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: @Stevan Slewa : It is a colloquial  hyperbole that means something is so delicious or wonderful, or a person is so attractive, that death would not be too great a price to have it, him, or her.  *The chocolate cheesecake is to die for.* or *She thought her roommate's boyfriend was to die for.* *That Tesla coupe was to die for.*

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following expression:

> easy to use

Nobody will ever say "easy to be used" even if it is implied that it's ment to be used by somebody.
English is a language that tends to simplify. It's not like ancient Greek where every little detail is reflected on the language itself. Don't try to reason too much about every English expression 'cause sooner than later you will find yourself in trouble with idiomatic expressions and other quirks.

Also because the context of the above sentence is quite poetic, you should expect the author to take some artistic licenses to enhance the dramatic effect of his sentences.